# Changing mask value for image in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

Is it possible to change the mask of each pixel by calculating mean value across the time?

```
var IC = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA')
            .filterBounds(AOI)
            .filterDate('2017-01-01', '2017-12-31')
            .select('B5');

var ChangeMaskAcrossTime = function(image) {
???
};

var output = IC.map(ChangeMaskAcrossTime);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is a little vague, though I see an opportunity to describe a few ways to deal with changing masked pixel values.

1. You can change masked pixels to a new value using the `.unmask()` image method:

```js
// Define a function to return a masked random image.
function getMaskedImg(seed, thresh) {
  var randImg = ee.Image.random(seed).multiply(100);
  var mask = randImg.lt(thresh);
  return(randImg.updateMask(mask));
}

// Get image and mask pixels w/ value greater than 50.
var randImg = getMaskedImg(0, 50);

// Change the value of masked pixels to a constant 50 (all
// values in the image less than 50 will be set to 50).
randImg = randImg.unmask(ee.Image.constant(50));
```

2. You can fill masked pixels by calculating a collection composite (i.e., calculate the per-pixel mean or median of all images in a collection - if an unmasked pixel observation exists it "fills" a given pixel with a statistic).

```js
// Make an image collection from the above defined function.
var imgCol = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([
  getMaskedImg(0, 90),
  getMaskedImg(1, 95),
  getMaskedImg(2, 99)
]);

// Composite all images in the collection by mean.
var colMean = imgCol.mean();
```

3. Combine the previous two options: for each image in the collection, fill masked pixels with the collection pixel-wise mean.

```js
var imgColMeanFilled = imgCol.map(function(img) {
  return img.unmask(colMean);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to take the mean of the ImageCollection (which reduces it to a single image)  there is a function for that:

```
var MeanOverTime = IC.mean()
```